# how to solve the following recurrence $T(n) \leq 2c (\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 17) \log (\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 17) + n$.

Tags: recursive-algorithms

The title is pretty much self-explanatory. I don't think I have the necessary math skills to solve the recurrence. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My question is how to simplify $ ... \log (\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 17) ...$.

Nowhere in the basic log properties do I see how to expand the following: log(x + y). Thus I am not sure hot to proceed.

Comment: I am not sure with some of the terminology you used in the question, but try using the Mclaurin series expansion for natural logarithm.

Comment: As written, this isn't a recurrence. Presumably you meant $T$ instead of $c$.