# how to expand the following -> $\log (x + y)$

Tags: logarithms

I know for a fact that it is not $\log x + \log y$, but Im unsure as to how to proceed.. I have checked the basic log properties but nowhere do they give an example of a statement like the one above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: cause it has no standard expansion, at least not a usefull one, for what do you need one  ?

Comment: There no such formula for $log(x+y)$ . But you can use the logarithmic series expansion if needed.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348956/how-to-solve-the-following-recurrence-tn-leq-2c-lfloor-fracn2-rfloor@DominicMichaelis, refer to this post and you'll see why I need it.

Comment: There is nothing pleasant. If $y\ne 0$, we can rewrite $x+y$ as $y(1+\frac{x}{y})$, and then get $\log(x+y)=\log y +\log\left(1+\frac{x}{y}\right)$. It is possible to imagine a situation where this could be useful.

Comment: You could expand using the Taylor series...

Comment: $$ \log(x+y)=\log(x)+\log(y)+\log\bigg(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x}\bigg) $$ 
or
$$ \log(x+y)=h \log(x)+k \log(y)+\log\bigg(\frac{1}{y^{k} x^{h-1}}+\frac{1}{x^{h} y^{k-1}}\bigg) $$

Answer (score 10):

There's no easy, or more or less generally useful, expansion of this thing. You could try though:

$$\log(x+y)=\log\left(x\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)=\log x+\log\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

The above is assuming $\,x>0\,$, and it doesn't look that nice or useful, does it? But who knows, perhaps under certain circumstances...

Of course, you can do the above factoring out $\,y\,$,  too.

Comment: After years, it is still useful.

Comment: Super useful :)